# Substitute for Parsley in South East Asia?

Tags: substitutions, herbs, asian-cuisine, parsley

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsley substitute](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6/parsley-substitute)

So I'm currently living in Thailand and I'd like to try and make some of the Italian-American dishes I grew up loving.  Most of the necessary ingredients are present and accounted for, except parsley.  I haven't seen parsley anywhere.

So what are some possible substitutes common to south east Asia that I can look for?